# Почему при записи формулы в Exсel формула пишется в нижнем регистре

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, excel

Для работы с `Exсel` используются: `Pandas`+`xlsxwriter`.
Вставка формулы:

```
for row in range(2, df.shape[0] + 3):
    worksheet.write_formula(f"D{row}", f"=СЧЁТЕСЛИ($'Лист1'!F:F;$Лист2!A{row})")`
```

Результат:

[image: результат вставки формулы]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте только английские названия функций и формул.

[Из документации](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_formulas.html):

> Excel stores formulas in the format of the US English version,
> regardless of the language or locale of the end-user’s version of
> Excel. **Therefore all formula function names written using XlsxWriter
> must be in English**